# Android Drag and drop of button

Tags: android

I am working in android, I am using a button. Now I want to perform drag and drop of this button.

This is my main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ll_first"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

 <Button  
   android:id="@+id/btn"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="drag me"
  />
 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code to move this button on mouse drag:-

```
public class DragdropActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private final static int START_DRAGGING = 0;
private final static int STOP_DRAGGING = 1;

private Button btn;

private int status;

private ImageView image;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        status = START_DRAGGING;


    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        status = STOP_DRAGGING;
        Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
            System.out.println("Dragging");
            Log.v("***Drag and drop **",
                    "me.getRawX and Y = " + me.getRawX() + " "
                            + me.getRawY());
            Log.v("***Drag and drop **",
                    "image position = " + image.getLeft() + " "
                            + image.getRight());
     btn.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0,0); //this is not working fine. 


            btn.invalidate();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

I think `btn.setPadding()` is not working correctly, please suggest me what should I do so that the button can easily move to the position of mouse or gesture touch ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved my problem like this.

```
    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        status = START_DRAGGING;


    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        status = STOP_DRAGGING;
        Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
            System.out.println("Dragging");

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    50, 50);
            layoutParams.setMargins((int) me.getRawX() - 25,
                    (int) me.getRawY() - 50, 0, 0);
            layout.removeView(btn);
            layout.addView(btn, layoutParams);

            btn.invalidate();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now its working fine.

Comment: I also tried this code, First the code doesn't work, but after changing the return value to "true" it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you should get button's layout params, set left, right, top, bottom and set these layout params back to button

Answer (score 2):

Try returning true from `onTouch()` method. That might work out. In one of my app it worked as return false was not moving the view as per my touch movement but return true statement solved it.