# Dragging a button on Android

Tags: android, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Drag and drop of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663404/android-drag-and-drop-of-button)

I have a `ViewGroup` and several image buttons inside this View group. I initialize all the buttons and set their layout parameters in `onLayout` and I also set their touch listeners in this method. However, I can't get the buttons to drag. I did `invalidate()`. Does anyone happen to know how I could go about making a button draggable inside a view group?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what's going on without the code. Please add some code.

Also, make sure you take a look to the following Drag and Drop official documentation

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html